# Read up to a null-terminator using read()

Tags: c++, c, unix

Is there an option, part of read() that when calling read() on a file descriptor it only prints out the characters up to the null terminator?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of fgets(), but that works on FILE *'s rather than file descriptors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, no, there isn't.  `read()` doesn't look at the data at all; it just reads as many bytes as there are (but not more than your buffer size).

I would do this with the higher-level `stdio.h` functions, by calling `getc()` (and writing to a buffer) until I saw a NUL byte, and then `ungetc()` on the NUL.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean *reads up to the null terminator* instead of *prints*, then no: it just reads the number of bytes you indicate unless one of the failure conditions listed in the manpage occurs, or it reaches end-of-file. (There are no NUL terminators in text files, but I assume you knew that.)

Answer (score 3):

Without using buffered stdio or your own buffering system, the only way to read up to a particular delimiter character, or any condition other than a fixed number of bytes, is to read byte-at-a-time. If you run shell scripts under `strace` you will notice the shell `read` command works this way, because it must leave subsequent input unread so that it can be read by other processes that inherit the fd.

Answer (score 0):

There is a case where read() will do line processing for you and this is when your file descriptor is opened on a terminal (pty/tty). You can set what your line delimiter is by manipulating the termio structure. I don't know if you can set NUL to be your end-of-line character though.